# CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

When I access my cloudfront URL, I get the following error:
CloudFront wasn't able to connect to the origin.

The S3 bucket has the correct policy. Cloudfront should be able to access it.

I have an ELB, S3 bucket, and a Site Endpoint as Origins. Is it the ELB? Do I need to do something special to give Cloudfront access to the ELB?

Here's the policy on the S3 bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPerm",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-static-content/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It should be really easy to determine which origin it can't access by trying to access a specific resource at each origin and see which one fails.

Comment: Also for your ELB, you need to allow HTTP/HTTPS access in the security group in order for CloudFront to be able to access it.